# LIST and TUPLE assignment operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Why only tuple changes in example II whereas both lists get changed in example I? Please consider these two programs and their respective output (I and II).

**I**.

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4]
L2 = L1
L2.append(5)
print("L1: ", L1)
print("L2: ", L2)
```

**Output**:
L1: [1,2,3,4,5]
L2: [1,2,3,4,5]

**II**.

```
L1=(1,2,3,4)
L2=L1
L2 += (5,)
print("L1: ", L1)
print("L2: ", L2)
```

**Output**:
L1: (1,2,3,4)
L2: (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Because tuples are immutable.  Instead of changing the tuple that both variables are pointing to, you are creating a new tuple and assigning it to `L2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, both L1 and L2 are pointing to the stored data so if you change any of L1 or L2, the data changes and by recalling (not sure the right expression) any of L1 or L2, the new changed data will be shown. This explanation was true for lists. Lists are mutable. 
In the second example, you're using tuples which are **immutable**. When you want to change an immutable tuple, python automatically makes a new tuple. It means that when you add 5 to the tuple L2, in fact 5 doesn't add up to the original tuple, python makes a new tuple named L2 with the new data (5) added to it and the original data (L1) remains unchanged. This is why L1 is not changed but L2 is.

Answer (score 4):

`a = b` makes `a` refer to the same object as `b`. But tuples are immutable, so `+=` creates a *new* tuple, leaving the original untouched.